# Undefined method for 'n' in ruby while loop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write an algorithm to solve the math problem Σ n = 1 to 49 of n(n+1). I keep getting an error "undefined method 'n' for main object"

```
def solver(n)
  sum = 0
  while n < 49
    temp = n(n+1)
    n+=1
    sum = sum + temp
  end
  return sum
end

puts solver(1)
```

Comment: You are missing a `*` for multiplication

Comment: Ruby does not work as math. `n(n+1)` makes ruby think that you are calling n as a function with an argument of n. Try `n * (n+1)` (as @IsmailBadawi said) instead.

Comment: Also, as a good practice, you should always indent your code correctly..

Comment: I know you're a newbie, but I thought you might be interested in a Ruby-like way of doing this calculation, which you can look forward to doing youself after you have gained experience with the language: `arr0 = [*1..49]; arr1 = [*2..50]; arr0.zip(arr1).map { |a,b| a*b }.reduce(:+) #=> 41650`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
temp = n(n+1)
```

put:

```
temp = n*(n+1)
```

Comment: "Insted" needs to be changed to "instead". 2000 downvotes. :P

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting `undefined method 'n' for main object` is because your code thinks that `n(n+1)` is calling `n()` method on the main object. In ruby `main` refers to the top level object which is an instance of `Object`

In any case, the solution to your issue is actually multiplying `n * (n + 1)` rather than calling a method `n` with argument  `n + 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of missing *. Try this solution:

```
def solver(n)
  sum = 0
  while n < 49
    temp = n*(n+1)
    n+=1
    sum = sum + temp
  end
  return sum
end

puts solver(1)
```